# Bot Framework Compose: Dynamic multiple choice action (from API)

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

I'm building a bot with bot framework composer (V2)

I want to create a multiple choice action, with choices that I get from a API call.

**Api Choices**

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "One",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Two",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Three",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Four",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Five",
        "active": true
    }
]
```

How do I bind this choices in the multiple choice action?
[image]

Comment: How you are trying to make it as multiple choice? Do you want to bind it using Aaptive card? Could you please share more details?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT , I'm trying to use heroCard from the bot framework composer.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I've added picture reference. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are able to call API and got the data in array format, suppose it got stored in `dialog.response`.

So what you need to do is,

1. Add a [*For each item: Loop*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-control-conversation-flow?tabs=v2x#loop-for-each-item) and configure it as shown in screenshot.[image: loop configuration]
2. Next, add [*Edit an Array Property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-memory?tabs=v2x#edit-an-array-property) **in the loop** and configure it as shown in screenshot
   [image: Edit an Array Property configuration]
3. Now, at the end, you need to add Multi-Choice(that you have already added) and give `dialog.choices` in *Array of choices*
   [image: Array of choices]

I have tested this flow till the bot sent card with multiple choice.
[image: Output]

Comment: Great, very useful! A tip, in version 2.1.2 I'm using you have the set the array in the choice via an expression

Comment: I have been stuck for hours trying to Push a value into an array with the "Edit an array property" action.  You showed me that I must leave the "Result property" box empty.  Thanks!